# Find the Row count of each value

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have table like

```
Name
A
B
B
C
C
C
A
A
B
B
```

I need Query to return output like

```
Name         count
A             1
B             2
C             3
A             2
B             2
```

I tried with rank(),dense_Rank().but i am not able to get output

Comment: What have you tried so far? Obviously we don't want to waste your time suggesting many things you have already tried. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: This is pretty trivial. A search on google gives you a lot of examples like http://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-with-group-by.php. Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Before we try to help you you should try to help yourself

Comment: What are the rows sorted by? How did you determine that the first 2 Bs are one group and the last 2 are a different group?

Comment: There is no group. we need to count the Number of record based on continuous occurrence of Name??

Comment: _Continuous_ is key word here - do you have any other column in your table, increasing id or something?

Comment: @PonderStibbons: i have unique Row Id for each row

Comment: You should have included this column in your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

In order to group the names and get the counts of names in every separated group, a simple count function with a group by or window functions does not solve your problem, I prefer to use two helper fields one for row number, the other holds a value for group number, you'll iterate through your table and increase the value of group field for the next name if it's not the same as current:

Assuming your table is:

```
create table tblN (Name varchar(10))
insert into tblN values
('A'),
('B'),
('B'),
('C'),
('C'),
('C'),
('A'),
('A'),
('B'),
('B');
```

following query is for above explanation:

```
    ;with cte1 as(
        select 1 gp,name -- add gp for group number
        from tblN
      ),
    cte2 as(
        select gp,name,
               row_number() over(order by gp) rn --add rn for evaluating groups 
        from cte1
      ),
    cte3 as(
        select gp,name,rn from cte2 where rn=1
        union all
        select case --evaluate groups
                when c2.name=c3.name then c3.gp 
                else c3.gp+1
               end gp,
               c2.name,c2.rn
        from cte3 c3
        join cte2 c2 on c3.rn+1=c2.rn
      )
select gp,name from cte3 --[1]
```

Result:

```
gp  name
1   A
2   B
2   B
3   C
3   C
3   C
4   A
4   A
5   B
5   B
```

now in above query instead of line [1] just use below query:

```
select name , count from(
select top 1000 gp,name,
       count(name) count
from cte3
group by gp,name
order by gp) q
```

*Result:*

```
name    count
A       1
B       2
C       3
A       2
B       2
```

Comment: I agree that this is not trivial question, didn't downvote, but OP didn't provide any column for ordering items.
Your solution is wrong because there is **no guarantee** that first subquery gives rows in order they were put into table.
If ordering columns were provided and they were distinct, increasing - solution is possible, yours is one of them, 
very similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849314/how-to-dense-rank-sets-of-values-that-repeat) was asked and answered lately.

Comment: @PonderStibbons, `1.` You are free to downvote or upvote if you feel a post isn't or is good and useful. `2.` the question you mentioned is not very similar. `3.` my solution is not wrong please test it before telling that. `4.` this solution exactly is for when there is no column for sort condition, don't think we always need to have a column for sort. `5.` you told _that first subquery gives rows in order they were put into table_ that's correct and it's desired that subquery should do that. `6.` anyway, I welcome your comment. good luck.

Comment: 1) I will 2) they are 3) is wrong because there is no guaranteed order, otherwise I would upvote it 4) the only alternative is rowid, which is fatal 5) but from what we know which row was put first?

Comment: Great, please note `without order by clause there is no guarantee for sort even if you have many other columns or cluster or none cluster indesex`  I just provided a solution to group the result exactly as like as the OP want it, `problem and question here is not about sort at all`

Comment: @Farhęg:sorry. i forgot to mention. i have unique row id for Each Row.

Comment: @kumar you are welcome, for this scenario and desired result having a unique field like rowid for each record does not help too much it does not eliminate the needing to group number for each separated group, willy-nilly we need an iteration on data to specify separated groups because a specific group of names like 'A' divides to multiple groups if there come other values like 'B' between them, I don't know a direct way for it.

Answer (score -1):

you can achieve your requirement very easy with following  query

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME) AS COUNT,NAME FROM TABLENAME )T ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: Hi kumar .. have u tryed this query or not try you will get accurate result .. you your are not likeing this post can pls explain